# TortoiseSVN Update Command Line Arguments

Tags: svn, command-line, tortoisesvn, command-line-arguments

I've run into an interesting annoyance that I'm trying to remove.

I'm creating a batch file to automatically update TortoiseSVN repos to the correct revisions for my technicians.

However, when executing `svn update` on the command line, SVN assumes that the current user login is the username for SVN.

That's not correct on our tech's machines. We have a local user of "Tech" that can be accessed by everyone and this user login runs the batch file. When we do an `svn update` from the batch file, it'll ask for a password with the username of "Tech" which isn't on SVN. Then it'll ask for a username and password input because it couldn't login with the previous credentials.

I'm trying to skip that unnecessary step, but I don't know other command line arguments (like `--force --no-auth-cache`) that will help.

Is there a way to force TortoiseSVN to ask for the username instead of assuming it is the login name?

Update: found the options for the command line on TortoiseSVN, but don't know which to use correctly - http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html

Answer (score 3):

> SVN assumes that the current user login is the username for SVN.

No, and never was so

From `svn help update`

```
>Global options:
>  --username ARG           : specify a username ARG
>  --password ARG           : specify a password ARG
```

But **The Right Way (tm)** will be

- Remove stored wrong credentials from `%AppData%\Subversion\auth` (most probably `\svn.simple`) (URLs are plain-text parameters inside files)
- Login once to needed repository (with any command, which require authentication) with `--username`, `--password`, using correct credentials
- Remove auth. data from update command (cached data will be used)